# How do you implement Lazy Loading images in listView

Tags: android

I'm referring to this popular marked answer: [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Perhaps, I don't fully understand the code, but how exactly would I apply it to my getView in my adapter?

I know there is another answer there that has an example, but supposedly that requires an sd card? Not all phones have cd cards.

Comment: You don't necessary require SD Card, similar logic you can just store the downloaded image as a Bitmap and cache in memory (extra care should be done on out of memory).

Comment: It's normally better to save in external storage as it is less restricted in terms of size. You can save in internal file system using `Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory()` for similar purpose too, without the need for SD Card. This directory allows about 1 or 2 Mb space (not sure the exact number). Android would not guarantee the stuff to be 'safe' and it might get purged sometime.

Comment: Here is my answer on lazy load of images into `GridView` which can easily be transformed for any adapter (as long as you have `getView` method) http://stackoverflow.com/a/17374461/1276374

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

This answer on the same topic just worked without any problem on my app.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

get the Lazy list example from below link

```
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList
```